# What's the reverse operation to jQuery.parseJSON();

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cookies

In javaScript, using jQuery library, I need to:

- Take an array of objects.
- Stringify it.
- Save it as a cookie.
- On refresh -> Parse cookie and 'recreate' the array.

Using JSON is easy.

```
// Write JSON Cookie
var foo = JSON.stringify(myValue);
writeCookie(foo);

// Read [Eat?] JSON Cookie
var foo = JSON.parse(readCookie("myArray"));
if(foo.length) {
    myArray = foo;
}
```

(Note: writeCookie(); readCookie(); Are 2 functions I wrote based on the suggested cookie functions on [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).)

Now, my user base involves a lot of pre-IE8 browsers. (Which won't support these methods). So I want to turn to jQuery to plug in the holes. [Parsing JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)  is easy:

```
// Read JSON Cookie with jQuery
var foo = jQuery.parseJSON(readCookie("myArray"));
if(foo.length) {
    myArray = foo;
}
```

My question is how do I write a JSON object to cookie using jQuery (Such that it will work for earlier versions of IE).

Thanks

Update: Still confused why jQuery would offer a parseJSON function and not a writeJSON function?

Comment: depending on the size of the array you might want to use localStorage instead as it has a higher length limit

Comment: Thanks, the array I'm storing isn't very big. Just storing information like 'Selected units', etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

Comment: @Jon Meh; That solution is to import another library. I'm already using a couple libraries. Don't really want to add another one. (I prefer not to blindly use other peoples code). I just assumed, because jQuery had a parseJSON function it would have a writeJSON function. Might be me being st000pid.

Comment: @User2: It doesn't because it doesn't need that functionality. If you need to support IE7 then you have to use a polyfill. It's not the end of the world.

Comment: @Jon Starting to see that. Yea. Thanks. Will polyfill. #theWorldIsEnding

Answer (score 3):

It's the native function [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify); standard jQuery does not provide a compatibility wrapper around it, but browser compatibility is not bad (will work on IE >= 8 and everything else).

Comment: But that is not supported by versions of Internet Explorer prior to IE8. jQuery normally has a way around backward compatibility.

Comment: @User2: That's true. I have found another question of which this is a duplicate where the answers suggest compatibility workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON2 library https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js for compatibility with older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to include the polyfill for [JSON](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) object.

But if you insist create a method for serializing an object to JSON notation inside the jQuery namespace, you can do something like this:

**[Serializing to JSON in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29574586/2247494)**